# JavaScript not clearing image array upon deleting preupload image

Tags: javascript, html, image, forms

I found this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ERZVC/2/) which is a partially working example of what I am trying to accomplish.  A multiple image upload with preview and optional delete option.  However, it appears when you actually hit delete, the preview simply goes away and the form still retains the images uploaded.

This error can also be replicated by trying to upload more then the allowed 5 images, if you upload say 7 images, it will alert that you cannot have that many images, however it appears that the image array holds onto 7 images and just doesn't show the preview.

How can I adjust the script to actually clear the image a user deletes as well as not allow the input field to accept more then 5 images?

Thanks!

```js
var count=0;
 function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var $fileUpload = $("input#files[type='file']");
  count=count+parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
  
  if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 6 || count>5) {
   alert("You can only upload a maximum of 5 files");
   count=count-parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
   evt.preventDefault();
   evt.stopPropagation();
   return false;
  }
  var files = evt.target.files;
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
   if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
    continue;
   }
   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
    return function (e) {
     var span = document.createElement('span');
     span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');
     document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
    };
   })(f);

   reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
 }
 
 $('#files').change(function(evt){
  handleFileSelect(evt);
 });  

 $('#list').on('click', '.remove_img_preview',function () {
  $(this).parent('span').remove();
        
        //this is not working...
        var i = array.indexOf($(this));
        if(i != -1) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
        }
        // tried this too:
        //$(this).parent('span').splice( 1, 1 );
        
        count--;
 });
```

```css
.thumb {
 width:40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0.2em -0.7em 0 0;
}
.remove_img_preview {
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
    right:5px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:0.9em;
    padding: 0 0.3em 0;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.remove_img_preview:before {
    content: "×";
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="image_file_arr[]" multiple>
<br><output id="list"></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see three places for your code improvement:

+When creating the image add an attribute that will uniquely identify the image

```
span.innerHTML = '<img class="thumb" data-id="' + i + '" src=" + e.target.result + '" title="' + escape(theFile.name), '"/>'
```

+When deleting get the image id and then slice the original array on its value

```
var i = $(this).data("id");
array.splice(i, 1);
```

+when looping and reading the file, if the count is bigger then 5 break the loop.